# How can the relationship between two nodes be captured using the Laplacian matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I am new to spectral graph theory, so I apologize if there are any mistakes in my writing. If I make an error, please kindly point it out and guide me in the right direction.

Now let me clearly state the problem.

Consider a graph $G = (V, E)$. We randomly sample nodes from this graph and keep track of the count $n_i$ which represents the number of times $i^\text{th}$ node is sampled. We define the edge weights to capture the similarity between the nodes. Specifically, when a node $i$ is selected, the count $n_i$ increases by 1, and this change also affects the nodes adjacent to $i$ based on the weight of the edges between nodes. To quantify this effect, we introduce a quantity called $n_i^\text{eff.}$ (effective count of $i^\text{th}$ node) which is given by

$$n_i^\text{eff.} = \left( \left[ N + (\rho L) \right]^{-1} \right)_{ii}^{-1},$$

where $N$ is a diagonal matrix of ${n}_{t=1}^n$ and $L$ is the Laplacian matrix of the graph. To find the Laplacian, we used weighted degrees.

Now, my question is: How can one arrive at this equation? I have gained an understanding of intuition by working through graphs with 2, 3, and 4 nodes. Specifically, I would like to know why we add the weighted Laplacian to $N$. Why do we take the inverse of this sum? And, ultimately, why does this equation work?

I am asking this question to understand the paper - https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.01152

The equation is given on page 6 of the paper.

Comment: "Why does this equation work" - work to do what? You've given an incomplete description of an algorithm (it's not clear what "this change affects the nodes adjacent to $i$" is supposed to mean) and you've given an equation that's supposed to "quantify this effect", but that's vague. The equation obviously doesn't describe the result of the random process, because it has no random quantities in it. Do you intend for $n_i^{\text{eff}}$ to be the expected value of some quantity? If so, what?